# AsyncHttpClient﹕ Passed contentType will be ignored because HttpEntity sets content type

Tags: android, web-services, androidhttpclient, android-async-http, loopj

Im trying to post some data using the android httpclient (loopj).I add some json data in its body and i set request header.But it shows AsyncHttpClient﹕ Passed contentType will be ignored because HttpEntity sets content type. Does any one know how to solve this issue?

```
 public static void post(Activity context,String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
            innerObject.put("Name", "@MODE");
            innerObject.put("ParamType", "8");
            innerObject.put("Value", "0");
            JSONArray ar = new JSONArray();
            ar.put(innerObject);
            try {
                jsonParams.put("ProcName", "Core.MENUS_SPR");
                jsonParams.put("dbparams", ar);

               Log.i("jsonParams.toString()",""+jsonParams.toString());

                StringEntity se = null;
                try {
                    se = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());


                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
                   client.post(context, (url), se, "application/json", responseHandler);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write this before post then it will work.

```
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
```

**Reason once you use some entity it will ignore content type given in post and use entity's content.** So, above line will solve your problem.

---

I dig into the source code and find out that your content type pass in `post(..)` will be ignored and if it exists then you will this error in logs.

> Passed contentType will be ignored because HttpEntity sets content
>   type

but don't worry once you give **content type to your entity** it will work. For removing this this error you can pass null in content type in `post(..)` instead.

Some code from **AsyncHttpClient.java**:

```
if (contentType != null) {
            if (uriRequest instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase && ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase) uriRequest).getEntity() != null) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Passed contentType will be ignored because HttpEntity sets content type");
            } else {
                uriRequest.setHeader(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
            }
        }
```

Comment: No luck Still get AsyncHttpClient﹕ Passed contentType will be ignored because HttpEntity sets content type

Comment: Just check my answer now. I think it is more clear to you now. Still have some problem ask freely.

Comment: Thank you.Acutally  the fix u suggested intially had solved the error.I forgot to add internet permission grr!! So the onFailure  call back was calling, I had no idea why it happens.Then tried to call the service using HttpClient then i saw the socket exception. Sorry and Thank you so much for  wasting your time for me